# Project Euler #23: Non-abundant sums

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm struggling with Project Euler [problem 23: Non-abundant sums](http://projecteuler.net/problem=23).

[image]

I have a script, that calculates abundant numbers:

```
function getSummOfDivisors( $number )
{
    $divisors = array ();
    for( $i = 1; $i < $number; $i ++ ) {
        if ( $number % $i == 0 ) {
            $divisors[] = $i;
        }
    }
    return array_sum( $divisors );
}

$limit = 28123;
//$limit  = 1000;
$matches = array();
$k = 0;

while( $k <= ( $limit/2 ) ) {
    if ( $k < getSummOfDivisors( $k ) ) {
        $matches[] = $k;
    }
    $k++;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r( $matches );
```

I checked those numbers with the available on the internet already, and they are correct. I can multiply those by 2 and get the number that is the sum of two abundant numbers.

But since I need to find all numbers that cannot be written like that, I just reverse the `if` statement like this:

```
if ( $k >= getSummOfDivisors( $k ) )
```

This should now store all, that cannot be created as the sum of to abundant numbers, but something is not quit right here. When I sum them up I get a number that is not even close to the right answer.

I don't want to see an answer, but I need some guidelines / tips on what am I doing wrong ( or what am I missing or miss-understanding ).

*EDIT:* I also tried in the reverse order, meaning, starting from top, dividing by 2 and checking if those are abundant. Still comes out wrong.

Comment: *"This should now store all, that cannot be created as the sum of to abundant numbers"* This merely stores all abundant numbers, which is an intermediate step, but not the end.

Comment: I have an inkling that the error in your train of thought is in the line "I can multiply those by 2 and get the number that is the sum of two abundant numbers". Here you assume that the sum of two abundant number must be the sum of two identical abundant numbers. That is if the abundant number is n then the sum is 2n. But could it not be that for two abundant numbers n and m the sum n+m also holds true? I have not verified this rigorously yet, but as you were asking for tips

Comment: @Pankrates I added full description of the *problem*, but your idea might be right. Will check ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An error in your logic lies in the line:

*"I can multiply those by 2 and get the number that is the sum of two abundant numbers"*

You first determine all the abundant numbers [n1, n2, n3....] below the analytically proven limit. It is then true to state that all integers [2*n1, 2*n2,....] are the sum of two abundant numbers *but* n1+n2, and n2+n3 are also the sum of two abundant numbers. Therein lies your error. You have to calculate all possible integers that are the sum of any two numbers from [n1, n2, n3....] and then take the inverse to find the integers that are *not*.

Answer (score 3):

> I checked those numbers with the available on the internet already, and they are correct. I can multiply those by 2 and get the number that is the sum of two abundant numbers.

No, that's not right. There is only one abundant number `<= 16`, but the numbers `<= 32` that can be written as the sum of abundant numbers are 24 (= 12 + 12), 30 (= 12 + 18), 32 (= 12 + 20).

If you have `k` numbers, there are `k*(k+1)/2` ways to choose two (not necessarily different) of them. Often, a lot of these pairs will have the same sum, so in general there are much fewer than `k*(k+1)/2` numbers that can be written as the sum of two of the given `k` numbers, but usually, there are more than `2*k`.

Also, there are many numbers `<= 28123` that can be written as the sum of abundant numbers only with one of the two abundant numbers larger than `28123/2`.

> This should now store all, that cannot be created as the sum of to abundant numbers,

No, that would store the non-abundant numbers, those may or may not be the sum of abundant numbers, e.g. 32 is a deficient number (sum of all divisors except 32 is 31), but can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers (see above).

You need to find the abundant numbers, but not only to half the given limit, and you need to check which numbers can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. You can do that by taking all pairs of two abundant numbers (`<= $limit`) and mark the sum, or by checking `$number - $abundant` until you either find a pair of abundant numbers or determine that none sums to `$number`.

There are a few number theoretic properties that can speed it up greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Below is php code takes 320 seconds

```
 <?php

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2G');
$time_start = microtime(true);

$abundantNumbers = array();
$sumOfTwoAbundantNumbers = array();
$totalNumbers = array();
$limit = 28123;

for ($i = 12; $i <= $limit; $i++) {
    if ($i >= 24) {
        $totalNumbers[] = $i;
    }
    if (isAbundant($i)) {
        $abundantNumbers[] = $i;
    }
}


$countOfAbundantNumbers = count($abundantNumbers);
for ($j = 0; $j < $countOfAbundantNumbers; $j++) {
    if (($j * 2) > $limit)
        break;                    //if sum of two abundant exceeds limit ignore that
    for ($k = $j; $k < $countOfAbundantNumbers; $k++) {  //set $k = $j to avoid duble addtion like 1+2, 2+1
        $l = $abundantNumbers[$j] + $abundantNumbers[$k];
        $sumOfTwoAbundantNumbers[] = $l;
    }
}
$numbers = array_diff($totalNumbers, $sumOfTwoAbundantNumbers);

echo '<pre>';print_r(array_sum($numbers));

$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);

//execution time of the script
echo '<br /><b>Total Execution Time:</b> ' . $execution_time . 'seconds';
exit;

function isAbundant($n) {
    if ($n % 12 == 0 || $n % 945 == 0) { //first even and odd abundant number. a multiple of abundant number is also abundant
        return true;
    }
    $k = round(sqrt($n));
    $sum = 1;
    if ($n >= 1 && $n <= 28123) {
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $k; $i++) {
            if ($n % $i == 0)
                $sum+= $i + ( $n / $i);
            if ($n / $i == $i) {
                $sum = $sum - $i;
            }
        }
    }
    return $sum > $n;
}
```

Comment: Please, don't post complete solutions. You are taking away the change for other people to solve it themselves.